# Equality of decidable proofs?

Tags: coq, constructive-mathematics, calculus-of-constructions

I want to know if the decidability of equality of two decidable proofs of the same proposition can be proved without any additional axioms in Calculus of Inductive Constructions.

Specifically, I want to know if this is true without any additional axioms in Coq.

$$\forall P: \texttt{Prop}, P \vee \neg P \Rightarrow
(\forall p_1 : P, \forall p_2: P, \{p_1 = p_2\} \vee \{p_1 \neq p_2\})
$$

Thanks!

Edited to correct the error:
Edit 2 to make `Prop` more explicit

Comment: What you wrote does not make sense. If $P$ is a proposition then $p : P$ is a proof, and you cannot form $p \lor \lnot p$. Did you mean your hypothesis to be $P \lor \lnot P$ instead of $p \lor \lnot p$, i.e., "$P$ is decidable"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the hypothesis "$P$ is decidable", i.e. $P \vee \neg P$

Comment: Take $P$ to be $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, and the statement is false, since you can easily inhabit $(\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}) \vee \lnot(\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N})$ with $\mathsf{inl}(\lambda x.\;x)$, and function equivalence is obviously undecidable. Are there any other conditions on $P$ you have in mind?

Comment: P should be a proposition. (Actually, in my development, I already use functional extensionality, so the statement can still hold for me, but let's ignore functional/propositional extensionality for now).

Comment: Function extensionality doesn't imply that function equivalence is decidable... And Neel's answer settles the general case: if P is an (inhabited) infinite type (which includes some types of Propositions if no extra axioms are included), then the implication fails to hold for $P\rightarrow P$.

Comment: I mean Coq's `Prop` when I say Proposition. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Neel points out if you work under the "propositions are types" then you can easily come up with a type whose equality cannot be shown decidable (but it is of course consistent to assume that all types have decidable equality), such as $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$.

If we understand "proposition" as a more restricted kind of type, then the answer depends on what precisely we mean. If you are working in the calculus of constructions with a `Prop` kind then you still cannot show that decidable propositions have decidable equality. This is so because it is consistent in the calculus of constructions to equate `Prop` with a proof-relevant type universe, so for all you know `Prop` might contains something like $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. This also implies you cannot prove your theorem for Coq's notion of `Prop`.

But in any case, the best answer comes from homotopy type theory. There a proposition is a type $P$ which satisfies
$$\forall x, y : P \,.\, x = y.$$
That is, a proposition has at most one element (as it should if it is to be understood as a proof-irrelevant truth value). In this case the answer is of course positive because the definition of proposition immediately implies that its equality is decidable.

I am curious to know what you mean by "proposition".

Comment: How would you have $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ inside `Prop`? Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing in the calculus of construction that prevents $\mathtt{Prop} = \mathtt{Type}$, is there?

Comment: The confusion here is about what is meant by "the coq system". If it is "the calculus of constructions", then $\mathtt{Prop=Set=Type}$. If the more accurate "Calculus of Inductive Constructions with 1 Impredicative Universe" then $\mathtt{Type}$ is meaningless without universe level annotations. As far as I know, $\mathtt{Type_1=Prop}$ is a consistent axiom (though inconsistent with EM for subtle reasons).

Comment: Sure, we have to tack an index onto $\mathtt{Type}$. The point for @AdamBarak to understand is this: because $\mathtt{Prop} = \mathtt{Type}_1$ does not lead to any contradiction in Coq, we can show that something cannot be done in Coq by showing that it would lead to a contradiction if we also had $\mathtt{Prop} = \mathtt{Type}_1$.

Comment: I see, so, 

$$(\texttt{Prop} = \texttt{Type}_1 \wedge \texttt{hypothesis} (\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N})) \Rightarrow
\texttt{False}
 $$

because functional equivalence is undecidable.
Since it is known that $\texttt{Prop} = \texttt{Type}_1$ is consistent, it must be that the $\texttt{hypothesis}$ is wrong.  ($\texttt{hypothesis}$ is the proposition in the question).

Thanks!

Comment: Still not quite right, because in Coq we cannot show that functional equivalence is undecidable. The statement "equality on $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is decidable" is what Martin Escardo calls a constructive taboo: it can be neither proved nor disproved in Coq. So the correct argument is: if $\mathtt{Prop} = \mathtt{Type}_1$ then $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a proposition, and the statement "equality on $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is decidable" is not provable. (Whereas you said: and the statement "equality on $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is decidable" is false).

Comment: So is "equality on $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is decidable" not provable even when $\texttt{Prop} = \texttt{Type}_1$, not just in Coq? 

(There seems to be two things which I still have to find/look for proofs of: "$\texttt{Prop} = \texttt{Type}$ is consistent in Coq" and "equality on $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is decidable" is unprovable in Coq + $\texttt{Prop} = \texttt{Type}$)

Comment: Actually, since we're doing this for Coq, we should probably consider $\mathsf{Prop} = \mathsf{Set}$. If you look at the rules (https://coq.inria.fr/doc/Reference-Manual006.html) and change $\mathsf{Prop}$ to $\mathsf{Set}$ everything, does anything strange happen, or do you just get Coq without $\mathsf{Prop}$?

Comment: The product rules are weird if we do that because they cause $\mathsf{Set}$ to be impredicative (but fortunately that is consistent). Let's ignore the inductive stuff, that'll be complicated and there is the pesky "singleton elimination". Hmm. Maybe there is a simpler way to see that there are elements in `Prop` for which we cannot establish decidability of equality.

Comment: Isn't the hypothesis *somewhat* equivalent to "syntactic equivalence of functions whose range is `bool` and produces the same answer is undecidable"?

Comment: What's your point?

Comment: I do not "intuitively" see why syntactic equality of such functions is undecidable. I think it boils down to finding (as you stated), a simpler way to see that there are elements in `Prop` for which we cannot establish decidability of equality of its proofs, even though the equality of the elements is decidable. Thanks for the discussion! I think I have gotten lots of leads.

Comment: By the way, just one more comment: you should look for an inhabited propostion $P$ such that its equality is not decidable. For if $P$ is decidable and has non-decidable equality, then $P$ holds, since $\lnot P$ implies that $P$ has decidable equality.